# Rails 5 need to find all parent objects associated with a collection of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I have a collection of children (Invoices) and I want to find all the parents (Orders), how would I go about doing that?

So Order `has many :invoices`.

How to find all orders associated with the collection of invoices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
invoices = some_logic_to_get_invoices
orders = Order.includes(:invoices).where(invoices: { id: invoices })
```

Comment: Success! It looks kinda strange to me that in the `where` you can ask for the *nested* `id` key in singular giving it a collection (plural) as a value.

Comment: @Code-MonKy this is because the `invoices` is actually an ActiveRecord::Relation object, which is a scope and then Rails' ActiveRecord knows that you want to "nest" this scope in the where clause. Take a look at `Order.includes(:invoices).where(invoices: { id: invoices }).to_sql`. Also, if `invoices` were an array, you would have to `map(&:id)` to do the explicit version.

Answer (score -1):

`invoices.map(&:orders).uniq`

Comment: That is the most expensive (performance-wise) way to do it. Also, an array of arrays, should be `flatten`ed. Don't ask Rails to do what SQL can do in a very efficient way